# Explanation for proof X.4.2 in Silverman's book

Tags: proof-explanation, elliptic-curves

I don't understand a detail in the proof of theorem X.4.2.b) in Silverman's book on elliptic curves (2nd edition), see below.

Here is the context.
We have some point $P \in E(\overline{K_v})$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve over a number field $K$ and $v$ is a place of $K$ such that $E$ has good reduction at $v$. We have an element $\sigma$ of the inertia group $I_v$. We have an isogeny $\phi : E \to E'$ defined over $K$ of degree $m$, and it stands that $P^{\sigma} - P \in E[\phi] = \ker(\phi) \subset E[m] \subset E(\overline K)$ and $P^{\sigma} - P$ lies in the kernel of the reduction map $E \to \widetilde E_v$. I've understood the proof until there.

Moreover, the reduction map $$E(K)[m] \to \widetilde{E}(k_v)$$ is injective (this is VIII.1.4). Then, **Silverman states that this implies that $\{ P^{\sigma} - P \} = 0$, but I don't see why**. I would agree if
$$ P^{\sigma} - P \in E(K)[m]$$
would hold, but we only know $P^{\sigma} - P \in E[m]$. How do I solve this?

Here is the caption:
[image: Silverman - The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves second edition]

Comment: A quick anser could be that good reduction is invariant under base change. Thus, up to replacing $K$ with a bigger number field, you can assume that $P^{\sigma}-P$ is $K$-rational.

Comment: @Ferra : thank you very much for your comment! But if I replace $K$ by a bigger field, say $L$, then how would I know that $P$ still lies in the kernel of the reduction ? That is, why would $\sigma \in I_v$ act trivially on $\tilde P$ ? Indeed, the point $\tilde P$ would now belong to $E(\Bbb F(L_v))$ (where $\Bbb F(\cdot)$ means the residue field) and not to $E(\Bbb F(K_v))$ (on which we know $\sigma$ acts trivially).

Comment: I don't understand your comment completely; $P$ doesn't necessarily lie in the kernel of the reduction, it is $P^{\sigma}-P$ that lives there. Anyway you don't need to look at that: just leave the proof as it is until "...is in the kernel of the reduction modulo $v$". Now choose $L$ such that $P^{\sigma}-P\in E(L)[m]$ and choose a place $v'$ of $L$ lying above $v$. Then $I_{v'}$ is a subgroup of $I_v$, so certainly $P^{\sigma}-P$ is in the kernel of the reduction modulo $v'$. On the other hand, the base-changed curve $E_L$ has good reduction at $v'$, so $E(L)[m]$ injects into $\tilde{E}_{v'}$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180004